# Pass data parameter from model to next page Prism Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I need to pass data from ViewModel 1 to ViewModel 2 using Prism.

`TodoItem` is my Model with the string:

```
public TodoItem _todotItem { get; set; }

private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
```

I assigned it in the constructor:

```
public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, TodoItem todotItem)
{
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    _todotItem = todotItem;
}
```

And this is the code I use to navigate to next page (including the parameter):

```
NavigationParameters navParams = new NavigationParameters();
navParams.Add("PassedValue", _todoItem.name);

_navigationService.NavigateAsync("SecondPage", navParams);
```

**When I set the breakpoint on `_todoItem.name` it says *null*. The data is fetched before I click the `listview`. What am i missing?**

**Edit:**

This is how I navigate (click from `listview`):

```
private EventItem _selectedEvent { get; set; }
public EventItem SelectedEvent
{
    get { return _selectedEvent; }  
    set
    {
        if (_selectedEvent != value)
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                _selectedEvent = null;
            }
            else
            {
                _selectedEvent = value;
            }
            NavigationParameters navParams = new NavigationParameters();

            navParams.Add("PassedValue", _todoItem.name);


            _navigationService.NavigateAsync("SecondPage", navParams);
        }
    }
}
```

I do use the proper ways to catch the parameter on the second `ViewModel` (However, I get *null* in the first `ViewModel`):

```
public void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
    if (parameters.ContainsKey("PassedValue"))
    {
        _todo = (string)parameters["PassedValue"];

        OnPropertyChanged("Todo");
    }

}
```

I use `HTTPClient` to fetch data.

Comment: If you had ReSharper installed it would tell you that your naming convention for `_todoItem` isn't correct.

Comment: @samis You mean to uppercase? I changed that but still null.

Comment: You can use `var navParams = new NavigationParameters();` instead.

Comment: The `TodoItem` **member** is a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties), so `public TodoItem TodotItem { get; set; }`, and `EventItem` a [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), so `private EventItem _selectedEvent`;

Comment: @samis Still null after changing this: var navParams = new NavigationParameters();

Comment: Maybe  `_todoItem.name` do not change when you get data ,you can check this.

Comment: I dont think it does because when i break point here: public TodoItem _todotItem { get; set; }

Its null. But why? @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Do you break point after fetach data?

Comment: The listview is already populated with data when I click the listview and try to pass parameters. @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Ok, if you use test data like this `navParams.Add("PassedValue", "testdata");` when you pass ,checking whether `OnNavigatingTo` work.

Comment: Confirmed that it worked. I was able to read out "testdata" in the second viewmodel.  @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Ok,it makes sure that your problem is not passing data.If `TodoItem` is populated with data,maybe problem is select even not get the value from  `TodoItem`.

Comment: Well, TodoItem gives me null strings even though I have fetched the data upon entering the page. @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: I didnt register the Page that fetches the data. But now I cant register the Page because its static. I need it to be static in order to set the listview in code behind (OnAppearing) (Cant find a way to display data in ViewModel only). @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access the property of a null object. You should perform a null check before trying to pass the value to your navigation parameters. If this value is null, you should present a failure message and not navigate.

Comment: Great,if generate new problem, you can detailed record in question.

Comment: I added reference for My Api interface in the ViewModel (constructor) but the navigation stopped working. Any ideas? @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: You can implement the method of the interface and register them in where you want use.

Comment: I did this: containerRegistry.Register<IService, Service>(); in App.Xaml.cs

Comment: and this in viewmodel: private readonly IService _restService;
        private ObservableCollection<TodoItem> _topSeries;

        public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> TopSeries
        {
            get { return _topSeries; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _topSeries, value); }
        }

and then in contructor:  _restService = restService;

This makes the navigation stop working. @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: I also added interface that is registered: "IService"

Comment: I've done everything according to Prism but the Model string is still null :( @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: To solve your problem need more code,and you can check that step by step from easy to complex.

Answer (score 0):

In order to capture the parameters on the second page, you must use `Prism.Navigation.INavigationAware`. Please, check the code below, maybe will help you out.

**./Views/ItemView.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms" 
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" 
    x:Class="Project.Views.ItemView"
    Title="{Binding Title}">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- List View -->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                  CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" 
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                  HasUnevenRows="True" 
                  SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.Behaviors>
                <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" 
                                          Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" 
                                          EventArgsParameterPath="Item" />
            </ListView.Behaviors>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Data Template Cell -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**./ViewModels/ViewModelBase.cs**

```
using Prism;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Navigation;
using System;

namespace Project.ViewModels
{
    // INavigationAware provides a way for objects involved in navigation to be notified of navigation activities.
    public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase, INavigationAware, IDestructible
    {
        // ...

        protected INavigationService NavigationService { get; private set; }

        public ViewModelBase(INavigationService navigationService) => NavigationService = navigationService;

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the implementer is being navigated away from.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the implementer has been navigated to.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {

        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

**./ViewModels/ItemViewModel.cs**

```
using Prism.Navigation;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Project.ViewModels
{
    public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        // ...

        private ObservableCollection<ItemList> _items;
        public ObservableCollection<ItemList> Items
        {
            get => _items;
            set => SetProperty(ref _items, value);
        }

        public ICommand ItemTappedCommand => new AsyncCommand(ItemTappedCommandAsync);

        public ItemViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
            : base(navigationService)
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemList>();
            // Load the data
        }

        // ...

        private async Task ItemTappedCommandAsync(object item)
        {
            var navParams = new NavigationParameters
            {
                { "ItemSelected", (Item)item }
            };

            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(ItemDetailView), navParams);
        }
    }
}
```

**./ViewModels/ItemDetailViewModel.cs**

```
using Prism.Navigation;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Project.ViewModels
{
    public class ItemDetailViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        // ...

        public override void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            // Capture the parameter
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(parameters);
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I need PropertyChanged in the ViewModelBase too but it says that im hiding something. Should I worry? Maybe I dont need PropertChanged. Thanks for the help. @Jader Oliveira

Comment: How do I catch the parameter with a string from the xaml in the new page? @Jader

Comment: `PropertyChanged` is already implemented via `Prism.Mvvm.BindableBase`, and then you can use in your properties. E.g.: `set => SetProperty(ref _isBusy, value);` @KalleP

Comment: `NavigationParameters` is a KeyValuePair, so you just need use the key 'ItemSelected' in order to pick the value object 'Item' > `var itemSelected = (Item)parameters["ItemSelected"];`

Comment: Thank you alot. Just hope I can change the itemssource to go to viewmodel instead of code behind. I had problems showing data when using viewmodel. @Jader Oliveria

Comment: Cant fint "AsyncCommand" and what is Item inside: Task ItemTappedCommandAsync?? @Jader

Comment: And I wanna use await So i cant load the data there. @Jader

Comment: Error in xaml when using your exact xaml page. @Jader Oliveira

Comment: @KalleP, sorry about the `AsyncCommand` it's a helper that I created in my solution, you can use just `Command` if you want.
Did you config Prism properly? Because the viewmodel must work...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Worked with Command. However, Im getting error when saving the xaml page with the ItemTapped things. I have these nugets from Prism: Prism.Forms, Prism.Unity.Forms, Prism.Dryloc.Forms, Prism.Core. @Jader Oliveira

Comment: I have also added:

xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
    mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" @Jader Oliveira

Comment: I followed this (https://xamgirl.com/prism-in-xamarin-forms-step-by-step-part-1/#comment-398) to set up Prism according to the v7 style.